# Cannot find location of the TFS Default Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am looking for the DefaultTemplate.xaml. Is it part of Team Foundation server or part of Visual Studio?

On MSDN it states how i can edit the file etc but it doesn't tell me where to get it from.

Can anyone assist me please?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of Team Foundation Server. You can find it in Source Control of your project in the BuildProcessTemplates folder:

```
$/<projectName>/BuildProcessTemplates
```

You can check-in your changes there or (better) create a copy and change it. The Build server will also access this folder, so you can select your template when editing the Build definition.

Comment: This is true for TFS 2010 and 2012. In 2013 they are stored in blob area and you have to download them from the Build Definition Process panel.

Comment: @GiulioVian: thanks for the hint. AFAIK this applies to the default templates that are also named differently in TFS 2013 (e.g. TfvcTemplate.12.xaml instead of DefaultTemplate.xaml). Customized templates still are stored in the Source Control folder. Also my newly created TFS online still has this folder. Or am I mistaken?